# Android application firewall - interactive prompt confirmation for connections

Tags: security, root-access, networking, firewall

I'm thinking of developing application, or probably extending AFWall+ app

What I'm missing on Android is possibility to confirm each connection from each application, simply blocking the application on some networks is already solved, but I want to have very specific control over what URLs/IPs the application is talking to.

I've made proposal https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/issues/269
Which is generally the same functionality as provided on OS X from Little Snitch application firewall. Possibility to create time-domain-port rules per application (unix uid/guid)

I'm thinking about using some kind of mashup of IPTables and possibly intercepting `sock_create` syscall. It will be open-source and free, if anybody wants to jump on the bandwagon, you're welcome.

So the question is, is there anything like this already done? Even paid applications.
I haven't really found anything like that, so I'd just like to be sure, before jumping into development of such large thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd certainly like to see something like this, the best I could find so far was [XPrivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) (root required) which you can setup to restrict Internet connections. However unless you apply a global template (license purchase required for batch apply) this is per app. Though maybe you can manipulate the system Internet process, I haven't investigated upon that so far (it's an expert setting with a very RED background, I don't want to mess up my system too much...). Though I'd certainly love to restrict tethering such that a connected Windows Laptop won't waste my data quota for updates...

Comment: I've since than found NoRoot Firewall, which is basically this, in form of local VPN loop, quite ellegant, but still lacks DNS names resolution (usually you don't know what is connections target) and rootkits/system apps are not obliged to use VPN connection.

Comment: @MarekSebera Thanks for the info, you could add that as separate answer in case someone else figures or how to extend that